# CPack to create Nuget package

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, nuget-package, cpack

```
CPack: Create package
CPack Verbose: Package files to: /home/testsystem/<path to build>/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/NuGet/MyModule.Linux.x86_64.nupkg
Attempting to build package from 'CPack.NuGet.nuspec'.
Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content.
CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.20.1-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/Internal/CPack/CPackNuGet.cmake:363 (message):
  Nuget pack failed


CPack Error: Error while execution CPackNuGet.cmake
CPack Error: Problem compressing the directory
CPack Error: Error when generating package: MyModule
```

I see the spec file the  tag is missing, is it because of it ?

Answer (score 0):

W/o seeing your `CMakeLists.txt` I can only guess that you don't have any files to install (with the `install()` command).